# In Perl 5, Term::Readline does not accept arrow keys

Tags: perl, terminal

I’m trying to diagnose and fix a bug I have with the Perl application `youtube-viewer` on Linux. I don’t know any Perl and this might turn ot to be a Linux question rather than a Perl question.

So when using `Term::ReadLine` in Perl 5, `readline()` doesn’t seem to accept arrow keys in my terminal – I tried with `rxvt-unicode` and `xterm`. Here’s a minimal example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

require Term::ReadLine;
$term = Term::ReadLine->new("");
$term->readline("");
```

Running this and pressing arrow keys `←` `↓` `→` `↑` prints

```
^[[D^[[B^[[C^[[A
```

on the terminal rather than moving the cursor.

Is this possibly a `Term::ReadLine` bug or how can I fix this? What can I do next to figure out what’s wrong here?

Comment: It works for me. Is your `$TERM` environment variable set correctly?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, it’s set to `rxvt-unicode-256color` which I believe should be correct for `rxvt-unicode`. So this probably is indeed a Linux question, right?

Comment: "This package is just a front end to some other packages. It's a stub to
set up a common interface to the various ReadLine implementations found on
CPAN (under the C<Term::ReadLine::*> namespace)."  You're probably using a different backend then before. Do you have Term::ReadLine::Gnu installed?

Comment: @ikegami That was it. If you make that comment to an answer, I’ll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to install `Term::ReadLine::Perl` or `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` as well. Try something like:

```
sudo cpan Term::ReadLine::Gnu
sudo cpanm Term::ReadLine::Perl
sudo apt install libterm-readline-gnu-perl    # if ubuntu or
sudo apt install libterm-readline-perl-perl   #
sudo yum install perl-Term-ReadLine-Gnu       # if centos, rhel, fedora
```